# ELMAH not logging exceptions if Custom error page is enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have this path /test/account and it has a code

```
throw new Exception("error");
```

in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
    </customErrors>
```

When it's mode is On, it shows custom error page instead of exception and elmah doesn't log it. When it's Off, it displays the exception and it's logged.

My understanding is that we need to log exceptions and we have elmah for that, however we don't want to display those detailed exceptions in production so we have custom error page.

I want that even though I display custom error page when there's an exception, I still want elmah to log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom error pages do actually "swallow" exceptions and as a result, ELMAH is never notified about the exception. There's a nice little trick to log handled exceptions, taken from [ELMAH and custom errors](https://docs.elmah.io/elmah-and-custom-errors/). Create this class:

```
public class ElmahExceptionLogger : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException (ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Then configure the filter:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahExceptionLogger());
}
```